# when to use @ in c#?

Tags: c#

I use @ symbol with local path only, but when do I use @ exactly?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You use @ before strings to avoid having to escape special characters.

This from the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#regular-and-verbatim-string-literals):

> Use verbatim strings for convenience and better readability when the
> string text contains backslash characters, for example in file paths.
> Because verbatim strings preserve new line characters as part of the
> string text, they can be used to initialize multiline strings. Use
> double quotation marks to embed a quotation mark inside a verbatim
> string. The following example shows some common uses for verbatim
> strings:

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\scoleridge\Documents\"; //Output: C:\Users\scoleridge\Documents\

string text = @"My pensive SARA ! thy soft cheek reclined
    Thus on mine arm, most soothing sweet it is
    To sit beside our Cot,..."; /* Output: My pensive SARA ! thy soft cheek reclined    Thus on mine arm, most soothing sweet it is    To sit beside our Cot,...
*/

string quote = @"Her name was ""Sara."""; //Output: Her name was "Sara."
```

Comment: Strings containing Window's paths are prime examples... Sometimes I swear this was the only reason for this in C#... "C:\\Program File\\etc\\blah\\blah" quickly gets old... Instead you can use @"C:\Program Files\etc\blah\blah". It's a little more readable, but no less functional. The only problem is, you now have to escape double quotes VB style, ie. @"""This is my test""" == "\"This is my test\""

Comment: You can also use it for strings that span multiple lines

Comment: Multiline strings are my favorite use of @, no more "SELECT x,y,z FROM that LEFT JOIN yaddayaddayadda" but a nicely formatted query.

Comment: Another common use is for regular expressions, otherwise you can need a lot of backslashes.

Answer (score 30):

AFAIK, You can use @ at any place where you don't want to let the default meaning of the thing persist. For example, @class will make class an identifier. @bool will make bool an identifier instead of a keyword.

You know the usage of @ before strings. It is used to indicate that take all the text of the string literally and don't treat any character in the string specially.

Edit: An yes, another thing to this is that `@Keyword` is compiled into a `Keyword` in IL.

[See this Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 25):

#### Verbatim Strings

An `@` before a string literal in C# denotes a [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx). In a verbatim string, only the quote escape sequence (`""`) is parsed as an escape sequence; all others, e.g. `\n`, `\t` etc. are ignored.

You'll have seen this syntax used with file paths, etc. because it's convenient to have the compiler ignore the backslashes in the path, rather than having to double-escape them, e.g.

```
var s = @"c:\Some\File\Path.txt";
```

is a little easier to read than

```
var s = "c:\\Some\\File\\Path.txt";
```

#### Reserved Words

You can also prefix [identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx) with `@` in order to allow using reserved words in identifiers. For example, `@class` can be used as an identifier, whereas `class` wouldn't be permitted. In this specific case, `@class` is a little less jarring (at least, I find) than the usual convention of `klass` or `clazz` which are often used to work around this restriction in other languages.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use keywords as variable  names

```
string @string = "Hi";
```

Comment: It's very useful in MVC, when You want to set html attributes like class: @class => "some.css.class"

Comment: thanks sauron, I can use @event as variable in my class even event is keyword in C#.

Answer (score 3):

You can prefix a string with the @ sign to avoid having to type 2 backslashes to mean one backslash.  This is why it is often used for local path because it saves some typing, and simplifies what you are looking at when you read it later.  When you have a bunch of double quotes and other escape characters, aka special characters - that's when you want the @ sign.  When you use the @ sign, make sure to put just one backslash when you mean backslash.  When using the @ you want to use the double quote character, put two double quotes instead of backslash, double quote.

```
String path = "C:\\path\\to\\my\\file";
```

vs

```
String path = @"C:\path\to\my\file"; //@ says one backslash is enough
```

here is another example:

```
String quotation = "He said, \"Wow!\""; //backslashes say not to end string
```

vs.

```
String quotation = @"He said, ""Wow!"""; //need a different method of denoting double quote
```