# What does "@" mean in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [when to use @ in c# ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057926/when-to-use-in-c)

F.e. `string sqlSelect = @"SELECT * FROM Sales".`

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057926/when-to-use-in-c

Comment: Fun fact: you can also use the literal prefix to distinguish an identifier from a keyword. `Int32 new;` is invalid, but `Int32 @new;` is not.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It means interpret the following string as literal. Meaning, the `\` in the string will actually be a `"\"` in the output, rather than having to put `"\\"` to mean the literal character

Answer (score 21):

Before string it allows different string formating rules. You can't use backslash to specify special symbols and "" (double quotes become quotes). I find this format very useful for regular expressions

Example

```
Console.WriteLine(@"\n""\/a"); // outputs \n"\/a 
Console.WriteLine("\\n\"\"\\/a"); // outputs \n"\/a
```

You might also seen @ symbol before variable. In such case it allows using special C# keywords as variables.

Example:

```
var @switch = 1;
var @if = "test";
```

Comment: Just stumbled upon this problem and it seems your comment for the second line is wrong. The output should be \n""\/a" - double quotes in the middle.

Comment: Is @switch just another variable?  Why name it like this, rather than calling something that isn't a C# keyword?

Answer (score 7):

It means there is no need to escape characters in such a string.

So if you want to write the path for c:\Windows, you can write it as

```
string path = "c:\\Windows";  // Note escaped '\'
```

OR

```
string path = @"c:\Windows";  // '\' need not be escaped
```

Comment: I'm looking really hard but I can't see the double \ in your first example...

Comment: Fixed. Seems some formatting issue.

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of string literals, regular and verbatim. The @ symbol makes it a verbatim string literal.

[MSDN: String literals (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

In C and C++, string has some special characters called "escape characters". For example `\`, `&` and the `"` itself is an escape character!

In the very normal way, you to print a statement like:

> Nancy Said Hello World! & smiled

you had to set your string like next

```
string str = "Nancy said Hello World! \& smiled.";
```

But people in Microsoft made a new cool feature in C# compiler so you can escape the headache of handling the escape characters by adding `@` before any string, and the compiler will handle all the escape characters for you by himself. For the last example you can have this in C# like next:

```
string str = @"Nancy said Hello World! & smiled.";
```

Comment: Agree with delimiting, but I don't believe & is a character that requires delimiting in c#

Answer (score 2):

> Verbatim string literals start with @
>   and are also enclosed in double
>   quotation marks. For example:

```
@"good morning"  // a string literal
```

Nicked from, have a look at the last few lines above the example for more information.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

Comment: also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx#Anchor_3

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to have a string with a `\` delimiter in it. `@"C:\A\b\c\d\e\f"` is legal.

Answer (score 0):

Used for string literal. It marks the string within the quote (") marks as the value without applying any interpretation for symbols in that string.