# How to play a sound in C#, .NET

Tags: c#, .net, audio

I have a Windows application written in C#/.NET.

How can I play a specific sound when a button is clicked?

Answer (score 288, accepted):

You could use:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\mywavfile.wav");
player.Play();
```

Comment: This is perfect answer because a new user can understand that SoundPlayer belongs to System.Media....

Comment: @Ali... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361857/what-does-means-in-c-sharp
"It means interpret the following string as literal. Meaning, the \ in the string will actually be a "\" in the output, rather than having to put "\\" to mean the literal character"

Comment: @Praveen's answer just gave another informative fact. Thanks to Dexter for asking that "@" symbol.

Comment: @bporter, this doesn't seem to work with mp3 files; it is restricted to wav format only

Comment: What a shame this API! It neither plays MP3 nor MIDI files. Completely useless for me. Windows has native support for MP3 and MIDI since at least Windows XP. Shame on Microsoft!

Comment: when I only need play standard sound like in messagebox show with icon, I prefer @miroxlav answer for most day to day need for .net windows app. it's simple and quick for example System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play(); or System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play(); System.Media.SystemSounds.Question.Play(); .etc

Comment: You can put the WAV in your exe folder and only pass the WAV name for SoundPlayer. (e.g. `new SoundPlayer("MyWav.wav").Play()`)

Comment: please tell me how to stop playing?

Answer (score 108):

You can use [SystemSound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsound.play.aspx), for example, `System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();`.

Comment: very useful. it can help to use system defaults.

Comment: It is important to note that if you turn off system sounds in Windows settings (at least newer Windows) it does not play anything.

Answer (score 36):

For Windows Forms one way is to use the `SoundPlayer`

```
using System.Media;

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav")) {
        soundPlayer.Play(); // can also use soundPlayer.PlaySync()
    }
}
```

[MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y171b18.aspx)

This will also work with WPF, but you have other options like using `MediaPlayer` [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.aspx)

Comment: Even better, in production code, create it only once and use it many times rather than creating it every time the button is pressed.

Comment: I'd rename that function to `ButtonClick`, simply because it seems like it follows the style of C# naming more.

Comment: @EthanBierlein - it was probably the naming convention when I posted the answer ;)

Comment: Huh. So that was the old convention?

Comment: @EthanBierlein it's still what is autogenerated by Visual Studio's Windows forms projects

Answer (score 17):

## Additional Information.

**This is a bit high-level answer for applications which want to seamlessly fit into the Windows environment.** Technical details of playing particular sound were provided in other answers. Besides that, always note these two points:

1. **Use five standard system sounds in typical scenarios**, i.e.

   - *Asterisk* - play when you want to highlight current event
   - *Question* - play with questions (system message box window plays this one)
   - *Exclamation* - play with excalamation icon (system message box window plays this one)
   - *Beep* (default system sound)
   - *Critical stop* ("Hand") - play with error (system message box window plays this one)

   Methods of class [`System.Media.SystemSounds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Media.SystemSounds(v=vs.110).aspx) will play them for you.
2. **Implement any other sounds as customizable by your users in *Sound* control panel**

   - This way users can easily change or remove sounds from your application and you do not need to write any user interface for this – it is already there
   - Each user profile can override these sounds in own way
   - How-to:

     - [Create sound profile of your application in the Windows Registry](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3668/Creating-Your-Own-Sound-Alerts) (Hint: no need of programming, just add the keys into installer of your application.)
     - In your application, read sound file path or DLL resource from your registry keys and play it. (How to play sounds you can see in other answers.)

Comment: Thank you for this extra information. I'd like to add an example: `System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand.Play(); Thread.Sleep(2000);` plays the sound **Hand**. Note that it plays asynchronously, here I added a sleep command to wait for the completion of the sound. If you don't wait, and play another sound, the previous one stops immediately.

Comment: @Matt – thank you for sharing. The possible issue with this (although unlikely) is that some user will change their *Hand* sound (as shown in point **2** above) for example to 3 seconds long audio and in that case, their new sound will be stopped after 2 seconds.

Comment: Right, you can't know how long the sound should be playing. Would be great if that could be queried somehow, or if there was a synchronous method waiting until it got played till the end. I [found another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046275/how-to-get-the-duration-of-mp3-track) dealing with this topic. In one of the answers it is described how you can get a timespan, with that you could determine how many milliseconds the thread.sleep parameter should be.

Answer (score 9):

Code bellow allows to play mp3-files and in-memory wave-files too

```
player.FileName = "123.mp3";
player.Play();
```

from http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,samples.aspx#sample6 or

```
Player pl = new Player();
byte[] arr = File.ReadAllBytes(@"in.wav");
pl.Play(arr);
```

from http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,samples.aspx#sample7

Answer (score 3):

I think you must firstly add a .wav file to Resources. For example you have sound file named Sound.wav. After you added the Sound.wav file to Resources, you can use this code:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.Sound);
player.Play();
```

This is another way to play sound.

Answer (score 2):

To play an Audio file in the Windows form using C# let's check simple example as follows :

1.Go Visual Studio(VS-2008/2010/2012) --> File Menu --> click New Project.

2.In the New Project --> click Windows Forms Application --> Give Name and then click OK.

A new "Windows Forms" project will opens.

3.Drag-and-Drop a Button control from the Toolbox to the Windows Form.

4.Double-click the button to create automatically the default Click event handler, and add the following code.

This code displays the File Open dialog box and passes the results to a method named "playSound" that you will create in the next step.

```
 OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
 dialog.Filter = "Audio Files (.wav)|*.wav";


if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  string path = dialog.FileName;
  playSound(path);
}
```

5.Add the following method code under the button1_Click event hander.

```
 private void playSound(string path)
 {
   System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
   player.SoundLocation = path;
   player.Load();
   player.Play();
 }
```

6.Now let's run the application just by Pressing the F5 to run the code.

7.Click the button and select an audio file. After the file loads, the sound will play.

I hope this is useful example to beginners...