# When using C++/CLI no sound is produced

Tags: visual-studio-2010, audio, c++-cli

I am trying to write a program in Visual C++ that will play a sound based on volume and frequency inputs gotten from pixels of a black and white video.  To start, I am first trying to get a sound to play sans parameters (which I will add in later).  I've already included winmm.lib into the project.

I've got code that compiles, but does not play a sound.  The code I have so far is as follows:

**sound.h (provided for me, works on another project):**

```
//file: soundthread.h
#include <Windows.h> //new
#include <mmsystem.h>

#ifndef SOUNDTHREAD_H
#define SOUNDTHREAD_H

class Sound {
    public:

        static void init();
        static void close(){waveOutReset(hWaveOut); waveOutClose(hWaveOut);};
        static void writeAudioBlock(LPSTR block);

    private:
        static HWAVEOUT hWaveOut;
};
#endif
```

**sound.cpp (provided for me, works on another project):**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "sound.h"
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <mmreg.h>

HWAVEOUT Sound::hWaveOut;

void Sound::init(){
    WAVEFORMATEX wfx; 
    wfx.nSamplesPerSec = 8000; 
    wfx.wBitsPerSample = 8; 
    wfx.nChannels = 1; 
    wfx.cbSize = 0; 
    wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
   // wfx.nBlockAlign = (wfx.wBitsPerSample >> 2) * wfx.nChannels;
    wfx.nBlockAlign = (wfx.wBitsPerSample >> 3) * wfx.nChannels;
    wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfx.nBlockAlign * wfx.nSamplesPerSec;
/*
    if(waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL)
    != MMSYSERR_NOERROR) 
    //  int tt;
    //  tt = waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, ((UINT)1), &wfx, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);
    //  if(tt != MMSYSERR_NOERROR) {
            fprintf(stderr, "unable to open WAVE_MAPPER device\n");
            int tt;
            tt = waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);
            MessageBox(0, "unable to open WAVE_MAPPER device\n", "Error", MB_ICONERROR|MB_OK);
    /* DBG:     tt=MMSYSERR_ALLOCATED;
        tt=MMSYSERR_BADDEVICEID;
        tt=MMSYSERR_NODRIVER;
        tt=MMSYSERR_NOMEM;
        tt=WAVERR_BADFORMAT; //** this is it //
        tt=WAVERR_SYNC;  // END DBG */

//         ExitProcess(1);
//    }

}

void Sound::writeAudioBlock(LPSTR block) {
    WAVEHDR header;
    ZeroMemory(&header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    header.dwBufferLength = 500;
    header.lpData = block;
    waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, &header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, &header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    do {
        Sleep(100);
    }while(waveOutUnprepareHeader(hWaveOut,&header,sizeof(WAVEHDR)) == WAVERR_STILLPLAYING);

}
```

**soundplay.h (created by me for holding the provided OnSound() function):**

```
#ifndef SOUNDPLAY_H //SOUNDPLAY_H_INCLUDED
#define SOUNDPLAY_H //SOUNDPLAY_H_INCLUDED

#include "sound.h"

void OnSound(); //update this w/ freq and intensity paramaters

#endif // SOUNDPLAY_H_INCLUDED
```

**soundplay.cpp (created by me for holding the provided OnSound() function):**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#include <math.h> //used to be under sound.h
#include "sound.h"
#include <mmsystem.h>
#define PI 3.141592653f
#include "soundplay.h" //new

void OnSound() 
{
    // produce a sin wave sound.
    float freq = 440.f;
    DWORD Fs=8000;
    int N=500;
    float* tt=new float[N];

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        tt[i]=(float)i/(float)Fs;
    }

    float intensity = 0.5f; //volume
    float *signal=new float[N];

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        signal[i]=intensity*sin(2.f*PI*freq*tt[i]);
    }

    BYTE* data=new BYTE[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        data[i]=(BYTE)(signal[i]+128.f);
    }

    delete []signal;
    Sound::writeAudioBlock((LPSTR)data);
    delete []data;
    delete []tt;
}
```

**Form1.h (code from the GUI designer containing the button that triggers OnSound to play a sound):**

```
#include "sound.h" //new
#include "soundplay.h" //new

#pragma once

namespace a2c {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 225);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"Sound Test";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(292, 273);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        //code for sound production
        OnSound();
    }
    //NEW STUFF
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 Sound::init();
             }
    };
}
```

The contents of OnSound and sound.h and sound.cpp are from a sound example project that was created in Visual Studio 6.0 and modified for Visual Studio 2010 that works at playing the sound.  My problem is that when I copy the code and try to use it in my own project, it compiles but doesn't play a sound when the button is pressed.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The C++11 standard does not know about sounds. You need an operating system specific library (or some other library abstracting above that, perhaps [libsdl](http://www.libsdl.org/)...)

Comment: You did check [all these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%5Bwindows%5DPlaying+a+sound+in+C%2B%2B) I guess?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : I don't think this is a C++11 question. It is definitely Windows (and their latest VC++ 2013 is only partially C++11 compliant). VC++ 2010 doesn't support much of C++11. OPs question suggests it compiles and runs but doesn't have the expected behavior of playing a sound. On a side note `mmsystem.h` is where Windows defines prototypes for basic functions of the Win32 sound system.

Comment: Why not just use .net? [How to play a sound in C#, .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502311/how-to-play-a-sound-in-c-net)

Comment: @crashmstr : not everyone uses managed languages for everything. Sometimes it is pointless and unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @MichaelPetch true, but they made a decision to use C++/CLI for WinForms, so why not also look at .net for playing sounds? (in other words, they are already using .Net)

Comment: @crashmstr : Good point about the C++/CLI choice. Although I know years ago many people didn't want to learn C# so they chose C++CLI because it was more familiar. MS sort of put a kibosh on that since they dropped IDE support for Winforms in VS2012+ when using C++/CLI. MS doesn't intend for people to use C++/CLI in the future for anything more than shim interfaces.

Comment: This may seem like a dumb question but have you verified the button press event handler is called? Either the sound code isn't working or the event handler isn't being called (and thus no sound)

Comment: And probably the most obvious thing. In `Sound::init` you fill in a `WAVEFORMATEX` structure but never actually do anything with it which probably suggests the sound system isn't being initialized properly.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I've already included winmm.lib in the project.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Your WAVEFORMATEX structure idea sounds like a good lead.  I'll look into it and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I haven't looked through every single one, just the ones that look relevant.  The weird part about this is that I took the sound.cpp and sound.h and the OnSound() function from a project that plays a sound when a button is pressed, but it doesn't work on my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael Petch was right about the incomplete initialization of the sound system.

I added:

```
int tt;
tt = waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);
```

to Sound::init() and it worked!

Thanks to all those who read and/or replied.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is scaling the floating point `samples` into 8-bit unsigned `data`. Since intensity is 0.5, samples is going to be between -0.5 and 0.5. Adding 128 and truncating to a byte will give you `data` values of 128 or 127 - which is effectively zero. To scale to the full range of the BYTE you need to multiply by 127.

```
BYTE* data=new BYTE[N];
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    data[i]=(BYTE)(signal[i]*127.f+128.f);
}
```

Additionally, unless you are okay with the quantization distortion, I would recommend adding some  [dither](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither#Digital_audio).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried it and it still doesn't make a sound.  I'm at a loss about what to try next.  Any ideas?