# How to get the duration of mp3 track?

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to ask how can I get length of my audio file in app.

I'm loading track like this

```
var installFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

var resourcesFolder = await installFolder.GetFolderAsync("Resources");
var mp3FilesFolder = await resourcesFolder.GetFolderAsync("mp3Files");

var audioFile = await mp3FilesFolder.GetFileAsync("sound.mp3");
var stream = await audioFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

mediaplayer.SetSource(stream, audioFile.ContentType);
mediaplayer.Play();
```

but I don't know how to get the duration of track?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to get the duration of the track:

- first is to read it directly from file's [MusicProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.musicproperties) by using [GetMusicPropertiesAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemcontentproperties.getmusicpropertiesasync):

```cs
   var audioFile = await mp3FilesFolder.GetFileAsync("sound.mp3");
   MusicProperties properties = await audioFile.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
   TimeSpan myTrackDuration = properties.Duration;
```

- the second option is to get its *NaturalDuration* from *MediaElement* or *BackgroundMediaPlayer*

Comment: Hi am always getting this Timespan value as 0(I tried both the ways which mentioned above). Anyone got the same problem ?

Comment: @Noorul Have you tried to get duration by MediaElement?

Comment: Yes i tried both the ways, here is my code
1) TimeSpan  duration = mediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
and 
2)MusicProperties musicProp = await storageFile.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
 duration = musicProp.Duration;

Comment: @Noorul With MediaElement - where have you put that code? Have you done it once the file is opened (for example in opened event)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, previously i was assigning it after assigning media element source. I tried with media element opened event. Glad it worked, am able to get the media length . Thank you so much .

Comment: The documents claim to only support Windows 8 and Server  2012 or later.

Comment: @tdyen It's probably as you say, thought the question was for method for WP8.1, where it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `mediaPlayer` is a `MediaElement`, you can get the duration using [`MediaElement.NaturalDuration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.naturalduration(v=vs.110).aspx).