# Play a sound, when moving over a button

Tags: c#, button, audio

I am wondering, how and if it's possible to play a simple sound, when the user moves over a button (button1) for example. I can imagine something like this:

```
if(button1.Touched) {// play sound }
```

Comment: You must really hate your users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play a sound in C#, .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502311/how-to-play-a-sound-in-c-net)

Comment: It isn't a duplicate. I am asking about the moving over, not clicking.

Comment: @MarcoBader And when you looked at the documentation for `Button` and looked for an event that would be triggered when the mouse was moved over the button you found...

Comment: Look for the MouseHover event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer mediaPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\Sound.wav");

public void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   mediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

Comment: Button has no `Touched` member.  This won't even compile.

Comment: Changed to MouseHover event