# Playing sound from application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, playsound

I have do a small 2d game in C#. I want to add sound. After watching a video in YouTube I have typed the following code but it is not running:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;
namespace Test_Sound
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SoundPlayer sound;
        public Form1()
        {
            sound = new SoundPlayer("3G.wav");
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(checkBox.Checked)
            {
                checkBox.Text = "Stop";
                sound.Play();
            }
            else
            {
                    checkBox.Text = "Play";
                    sound.Stop();   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio is showing the following error:

> line :27 Error    1   'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox' does not contain a definition for 'Play' and no extension method 'Play' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\hp\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Test_Sound\Form1.cs
>
> line 32: Error    2   'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox' does not contain a definition for 'Stop' and no extension method 'Stop' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\hp\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Test_Sound\Form1.cs

Can any one help me fix my error?

The Video link is [Play Sounds in Windows Forms App (C# .NET)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOh4ooHg1UU)

I have fixed that error. But now i have got exception. Visual Basic showing the following exception message at line number 27.
The exception message has given below:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Sound API only supports playing PCM wave files.
I have downloaded a PCM wave file from internet and replaced the existing file by it. But it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried to understand the error message? It is very accurate and it pinpoints the problem exactly. It gives you also an indirect hint how to solve the problem.

Comment: Should probably be: `sound.Play()` and `sound.Stop()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play a sound in C#, .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502311/how-to-play-a-sound-in-c-net)

Comment: @Black Swan, see my updated Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Play()`and `Stop()` are `sound`'s  methods that you declared before `Form1()`initialization.

Your code must be:

```
 private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if(checkBox.Checked)
     {
         checkBox.Text = "Stop";
         sound.Play();
     }
     else
     {
         checkBox.Text = "Play";
         sound.Stop();
     }
}
```

See:
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/soundplayer
 
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Media.SoundPlayer_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

About your new Exception, PCM (Pulse Code Modulation - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) is the only one supported by the System.Media.SoundPlayer class. It's the most common WAV format, so most .WAV files just work.

There are a few tools that can convert audio files.  For example, Switch Audio (http://www.nch.com.au/switch/) can convert between formats (even in the free version).  You'll need to get your file into a standard, PCM encoded WAV file.