# How do I make a music start in thebackground when my program starts in c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a .wav music file start whenever the program starts. **No, I am not trying to make music play when the user click on a button**, I am trying to make music start by itself whenever the program starts.

I need it for my C# program.

Comment: Are you using WinForms ?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio!

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502311/how-to-play-a-sound-in-c-net Start it in your "Main" method.

Comment: So you are saying just add the command in the "Main" section of the code?

Comment: Read the answer there, and put it in your "Main" method. If you start your program, "Main" will be your start point.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking all over the web for this answer!

:)

Comment: The marked duplicate discusses playing sound. To start playing music when your program starts, you start the music in the same place you'd put anything you want to happen when your program starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SoundPlayer and call it in Main method:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\test.wav");
  player.Play();

  // do something else....
}
```