# Take sound effect from video

Tags: c#, audio, soundeffect

I need a digital typeing sound effect.when numbers are typed,Sound effect appears in background of the video.I want to make a program that when I press the keyboard, I also listen this sound effect.How can I find this sound effect or take from this video?

the sound effect between 0:50 and 1:15

www.youtube.com/embed/kIXNpePYzZU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 'extracting the sound effect' part of the question, you would likely want to use an online video/audio downloader/converter. In the past, I have used [youtube-mp3.org](http://www.youtube-mp3.org/) and [clipconverter.cc](http://www.clipconverter.cc/).

For the second part of the question, it depends what exactly you want. If you want it to apply only to a specific text box in a WinForms/WPF/UWP app you are writing, this should be reasonably easy. The exact method depends on what you are doing, but involves adding a keydown, keyup, or keypress event handler to the text box

If you want it system wide, this is more difficult. Searching for 'Global Keyboard Hook C#' appears to give good results.

Once you have detected the key press, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3502311/4149474) for how to play the sound. The answer by bporter gives the following code:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\mywavfile.wav");
player.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://www.youtube-mp3.org/) to convert the video to mp3. Clip the sound effect out of the mp3. Then play the mp3 file with your code.