# How do i load a folder in to a list box?

Tags: c#

im trying to load a folder with .mp3 files into a listbox and be able to play them, this is the code i have tried and it loads the folder but doesent allow me to play the files

```
private void PopulateListBox(ListBox lsb, string Folder, string FileType)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);
    foreach(FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        lsb.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025626/playing-a-mp3-file-in-a-winform-application or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502311/how-to-play-a-sound-in-c-net

Comment: Invoke the magical play method `MagicPlay();`

Comment: I supposed you're using a dialog to select a folder and pass the full path to your method, have you tried with var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\temp\*.mp3"); instead of DirectoryInfo;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //Try this.
    using System;
    using WMPLib;
    using System.IO;

    namespace _myNamespace
    {
      public partial class Form1:Form
      {
         //to use 'WindowsMediaPlayer' you need to import WMPLib
         //add a reference "Windows Media Player" from the COM section of vstudio reference manager.

         WindowsMediaPlayer player;
         //constructor
         public Form1
         {
           InitializeComponent();
           PopulateListBox("folder");
           player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
         }

        private void PopulateListBox(string folder)
        { 
           string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
           foreach(string file in files)
              listbox1.Items.Add(file);
        }

        private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string file = listbox1.SelectedItem as string;
           if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file))
           {
              player.URL = file;
              player.controls.play();
           }
         }


      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void PopulateListBox(ListBox lsb, string Folder, string FileType)
{
    string[] files  = Directory.GetFiles(Folder);

    foreach(string file in Files)
    {
        lsb.Items.Add(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting an exception or it simply doesn't work?

Comment: if you are getting an exception please post it, and with the line that throws it.

Comment: the mp3 files loads in the listbox but wneh i try to play the i get an error          "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in windowsFormApplication17.exe"