# What are my options/resources for playing audio in C#?

Tags: c#, audio

I'm aware of how to play sound in C#, 
for example:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\local_file.wav");
player.Play();
```

However, I wanted to know if C# contained some sort of sound library, like files that are built in to the system that I can use, or something that generates sound (e.g. text to speech.) Basically, I just want to know what my options are for playing sound in my program, and/or whether I have any "resources" other than my own downloaded files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play a sound in C#, .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502311/how-to-play-a-sound-in-c-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is a progamming language.  It runs on many different platforms, each of which support many different libraries.

The [SoundPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=netframework-4.7.2) class in the .Net [System.media](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media?view=netframework-4.7.2) namespace is one very good choice for Windows.  Similarly [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) or [IRKlang](https://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/) might be good choices for doing audio in C# on Linux.

There isn't necessarily any "single best, one size fits all" choice.  You have many different options, depending on your platform, your requirements, and your personal preferences.