# how to play a .wav file using c#

Tags: c#, .net, media, playback, voice

I am new to `System.Media` and I want to simply play the sound of a `.wav` file using `c#` I did exactly what is written in this question's answars]([How to play a sound in C#, .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502311/how-to-play-a-sound-in-c-net)) and it won't work.
I used special `.wav` file that is especially for testing so it can`t be the problem.  the `file path` cant be the problem either, as I copied it and not manually typed it.

I don't know what have I done wrong, no errors.
thank you in advance!

here is the code

```cs
// using System.Media;
  const string soundLocation = @"cannot share the actual path but its not the problem anyway";
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(soundLocation);
            player.Play();
```

[wav file](https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_WAV_1MG.wav)

Comment: In what **specific** way does it not work?

Comment: its just runs. no audio

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] (that we could copy and paste into a console app to reproduce the issue).

Comment: What's the scope of this `new SoundPlayer`?

Comment: So your application will close after this? So dont tell it, show it. It helps us help you.

Comment: Does adding `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of your `Main` method make it work?

Comment: @mjwills yes! it was the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the sound to play, you could use:

```
player.PlaySync();
```

rather than:

```
player.Play();
```

The reason that the latter doesn't work is that your program exits too quickly (once execution gets to the end of the `Main` method). `PlaySync` avoids this issue by using the [current thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.playsync?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Media_SoundPlayer_PlaySync) rather than a [new thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.play?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to add the wav file ass a resource in C#. Once you do that you can do the following

Using System.Media;

System.Media.SoundPlayer Song1 = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.MoreThanEverything);
//MorThanEverything is a resource name for your wav file
.
.
Song1.Play();

Comment: How would pulling the `.wav` file's path change the way `.Play()` behaves?

Comment: To be honest not sure. This way worked for me so I thought I'd share it.

Comment: Also, I believe adding a wav file as a resource is better than hard coding a path because when you publish the app you won't have to worry about that file being in that path