# how to create a sound notification while application in system tray C#

Tags: c#

I have code for showing text notification. How can I create voice/sound notification?

```
     notifyIcon1.Icon = new       System.Drawing.Icon(Path.GetFullPath(@"image\not.ico"));  
    notifyIcon1.Text = "Application Notification";  
    notifyIcon1.Visible = true;  
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Hi";  
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Click Here to see details";  
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(100);
```

Comment: Use the [SoundPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) class with an Embedded Resource?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play a sound in C#, .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502311/how-to-play-a-sound-in-c-net)