# Play .wav audio file by enter the audio filename in the textbox c#

Tags: c#

Bingo caller program:

I would like to create a program to play series of audio files named as 1 through 10. As I entered the filename in the textbox, the program should play the audio file and display the numbers already played on board or something.

The audio file as follow:

1.wav
2.wav
3.wav
….

I am brand new to the c#….please advise !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This program is similar bingo caller…but I want to play the audio file for the numbers 
I just downloaded and installed the visual studio and do some reading about c#

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour); read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Maybe you can start with your app which contains the textbox and proceed with the next steps

Comment: Thanks ! I will try to create something.

Comment: Probably just start with a WinForm app, drag drop controls onto the form like Labels, 1 to 10. Add a textbox and a button. Double click the button and write code or google *c# winform play audio file* and you'll hit this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3502334/495455 - then code the labels to be set, `label1.Text = "Track 1 Played";`

Comment: I got it played the wav audio file format . 

Now I am trying to make a playlist which i named the song as 1.wav 2.wav …through 90.wav   Second i made a text box when I type in textbox as #1 , and click add button …i want to send these audio files to listbox and play from the list box …please advise

Comment: I meant a playlist in the listbox and use a button to send the audio file (ie: i typed in 1, the add button will send 1.wav to listbox and play that audio file…then do the same to 2.wav &&&& 90.wav