# How do i play the "Windows Hardware Insert" and "Windows Hardware Remove" sounds using c# (.net)?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, system

Im trying to play the Windows Hardware Sounds using a C#(.net) Console Application. But I can only find how to play the beep sound using SystemSounds.

I tried to use SystemSounds for this, but it can only do the Beep Sound using

```
SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a more general solution would be to play the wanted sounds by using a SoundPlayer object, where the only thing you need is the wanted sound file.

You'll be able to reuse this component in a future case where you'd like to play other sounds.

[How to play a sound in C#, .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502311/how-to-play-a-sound-in-c-net)

Hope that helps.