# What does the @ sign mean in the following - Class.Field = @"your text here"; -

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does “@” means in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361857/what-does-means-in-c)

What does the sign @ mean in the following:

Class.Field = @"your text here";

I came across this in a piece of code, the compiler does not seem to complain... I've searched around to no avail...

What does the @ mean?

Comment: You will find more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

Comment: For your future reference the name of this feature is "verbatim string literals". That should help you do web searches for it, and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It indicates a *verbatim* string literal. You can use it so escapes aren't treated as such:

```
string path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\UserName\\My Documents";
```

Becomes:

```
string path = @"C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\My Documents";
```

Comment: <pedantic>Actually, both are string literals.  With the `@` sign it's a *verbatim* string literal.</pedantic>

Comment: `+1` For beating me by ~35 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like

```
@"C:\temp\testfile.txt"
```

Without @ you would need to do

```
"C:\\temp\\testfile.txt"
```

Also it helps you work with other more complicated strings that should represent XML, for example.

Only one thing that you would need to double-write is " itself.

So, `@"Tom said ""Hello!""";`

Answer (score 0):

It a short hand so that  \ isn't needed to escape the backslash.

In regular expressions, it is very useful because Regex relies so heavily on the backslash character. When using the @ sign, the only character that you need to escape is the double quote, and it is escaped with a second double quote (a al VB).  All other characters are literal.

(Directory paths are another form of string that benefits from the @)

In your example, the @ is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It tells the compiler not to consider the backslash character as an escape sequence.