# How to use \ in a string in C#

Tags: c#

I want to use \ in a string, like

```
string str="abc\xyz";
```

But this is giving me error.

I have also tried

```
string str="abc\\xyz";
```

But still it isnt working.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: (I agree with all answers, but) what is the result of the second try (which should work) and what were you expecting ?

Comment: Effectively a duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057926/when-to-use-in-c

Comment: That will definitely work - post a snippet if you are still having issues - perhaps it is somewhere other than that particular line.

Comment: Shouldn't the second example just be `string str = "abc\\xyz"` - i.e. just *two* back slashes? Having three gives "unrecognised escape sequence"

Comment: @Timores - the second result shouldn't work; there are three backslashes which results in \\ and \xyz - since \xyz is not valid hex, the compiler will reject it.

Comment: @ChrisF: It was originally shown as two, but three in the source. When Finglas edited it to make it show up as a code snippet, it started showing as three. It's hard to say what was in the original code...

Comment: @Jon - I did see that, but I was reluctant to change it just in case the three backslashes were somehow in the original code.

Comment: @Richard, sorry, when I looked at the question, there were 2 backslashes in the second try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "abc\\xyz";
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

This works fine. It prints `abc\xyz`.

Answer (score 17):

You can either escape the character, like so:

```
string str="abc\\xyz";
```

or use a verbatim string literal like so:

```
string str=@"abc\xyz";
```

So your second example should work.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx) for more information.

Comment: FYI, the latter is called a `verbatim string literal`.

Comment: Got an upvote on a 9 year old answer. I love this place.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the latter (`"abc\\xyz"`) will certainly result in a backslash in the string - or you could use a *verbatim string literal*:

```
string str = @"abc\xyz";
```

Note that if you use the debugger to look at your strings, it will often (always?) "escape" them for you, so you'd see `"abc\\xyz"`. This can cause a fair amount of confusion. Either look at the characters individually, or print the string to the console.

You haven't said in what *way* it "isn't working" - could you give more details? If it's just the debugger output, then the above may be all you're looking for - but otherwise you should tell us what you're seeing vs what you expected to see.

Have a look at my [article about strings](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/strings.html) for more information about strings in general, escaping, the debugger etc.

Comment: Yes. While debugging i see abc\\xyz when i used @"abc\xyz".

Comment: And due to this i am unable to do anything further in my code.

Comment: @Brigadier: But that's the correct data. Why does the debugger showing you the right data but as a verbatim string literal make you "unable to do anything further in [your] code"? What's actually *stopping* you from continuing? What unexpected results are you getting apart from seeing the string in verbatim string literal format?

Comment: I am extracting the substring after \ from abc\xyz i.e.i want xyz.
But by writing string str=@"abc\xyz" i am getting \xyz.

Comment: @Brigadier: Then your code to extract the substring is broken. I suspect you're missing a "+1".

Comment: string result = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf("\") + 1); // Incase anybody's wondering...

Answer (score 5):

```
string str="abc\\xyz";
```

Normally, this should work. An alternative is:

```
string str = @"abc\xyz";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
string str = @"abc\xyz";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = @"abc\xyz";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
string str = @"abc\xyz";
```

That tells says that the slash is significant and not an escape character.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to prefix the string with the '@' symbol to stop the compiler trying to treat it as an escape sequence. So `string str = @"abc\xyz";` should work.