# For what it's worth starting an string in C# with @

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the @ in front of a string for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-for-net)
>   [when to use @ in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057926/when-to-use-in-c)

I'm quite new at C# programming and, in many examples, in particular at MSDN, the following code piece appears quite frequently:

string NewString = @"Hello World";

I'm quite curious about what's the effect of the @ signal used in this code... is by any chance different than

string NewString = "Hello World";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` introduces a raw string, which isn't preprocessed for escape sequences, such as `\t`. It is very convenient for regular expressions, which almost always include backslashes.